# HTML5 Canvas clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas, clipboard

I'm currently trying to implement a clipboard solution for my html5 text editor.
We are using canvas and struggle bigtime with getting 100% copy paste with all browsers.
I have checked out zeroclipboard but it has its limitations.

Is there any other ways to go?

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna be a short answer, but you should be able to use the [Clipboard API](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) which currently has [broad but partial support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard).

From the specs:

> This specification defines the common clipboard operations of cutting,
>   copying and pasting, in such a way that they are exposed to Web
>   Applications and can be adapted to provide advanced functionalities.
>   Its goal is to provide for compatibility where possible with existing
>   implementations.

The API is event driven.

Comment: Thank you, i will most definitely check this out.
On a sidenote, is there any place i can check what "partial" is defined as?

Comment: @user3264986 All I can see from the page is the note at the bottom: "Partial support in IE refers using a non-standard method of interacting with the clipboard. For other browsers it refers to not supporting the ClipboardEvent constructor." Also check the resources for details. Hope this helps.